# Remove UIViewcontroller from Presentmodelview stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

i want to remove UIViewcontroller from a stack of present model view

i have below scene

```
UIViewcontrollerA 
UIViewcontrollerB 
UIViewcontrollerA 
UIViewcontrolleC
UIViewcontrolleA
UIViewcontrolleA
```

i want to remove all UIViewcontrolleA from this presented view controllers.

How do i get these?
so the output will be

```
 UIViewcontrollerB 
 UIViewcontrolleC
```

i can easily do it in navigation controller ,similarly need in presentmodelcontroller.

```
NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[allViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[allViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:1];

[self.navigationController setViewControllers:allViewControllers animated:YES];
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You should rethink your entire app architecture if you're running into this as a problem.

Comment: i have below architecture: loginview->tabbar(with embedded UINavigationController)-> then this UIViewcontrolleA need to be call from anywhere.....and also UIViewcontrolleA need to be call from a button in it to reload different data in it . i had trying to reload UIViewcontrolleA

Comment: Or simply just need to remove all view controller presented to go back to base

Comment: "Or simply just need to remove all view controller presented to go back to base" Then do that. Just dismiss back to "base". No problem.

Answer (score 1):

[`dismiss​View​Controller​Animated:​completion:​`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismissviewcontrolleranimated) when invoked on a vc will remove it and anything presented above it.

```
A->B->C->D->E
```

So to dismiss, say D and E in the above stack, just invoke dismiss on C.  To restore D and E, present them again without animation.  You'll need to keep track of this A,B,C... array yourself.

Also note that the fact that you see so little support for this in the SDK is evidence that the idea isn't encouraged.